# how to submit a value and select that option in next page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I don't know much of HTML, so when I click on a button say with a value `life`, when I click on this button, it should go to the next page (which is a contact form) and should select that option from the drop down list.

first page

```
<input type="submit" name="type" value="trauma">
```

second page

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type">
    <option value="life" >Life Insurance</option>
    <option value="trauma">Trauma Insurance</option>
    <option value="tpd">Total &amp; Permanent Disability Insurance</option>
    <option value="income">Income Protection Insurance</option>
    <option value="redundancy">Redundancy Insurance</option>
    <option value="private">Private Medical Insurance</option>
    <option value="mortgage">Mortgage Protection Insurance</option>
    <option value="health">Health Insurance</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone suggest me a server side or a cliet side code?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are many ways to tackle this. On the first page (lets call it `first_page.php`), set up a form. The `action=""` attribute should point into the second page (lets call it `second_page.php`). So then the second page should be able to get the values that came from the first page and process it. In this example, the `$_GET` is used.

`first_page.php` (Simple Form)

```
<form method="GET" action="second_page.php">
    <h1>Select Insurance</h1>
    <button type="submit" name="button" value="life">Life</button>
    <button type="submit" name="button" value="trauma">Trauma</button>
</form>
```

This is just a simple form. `method="GET"`, `action="second_page.php"`

`second_page.php`

```
// if there is a button variable
$selected = '';
if(isset($_GET['button'])) {
    $selected = $_GET['button']; // get the value
}

// default select values
$select_values = array(
    'life' => 'Life Insurance',
    'trauma' => 'Trauma Insurance',
    'tpd' => 'Total &amp; Permanent Disability Insurance',
    'redundancy' => 'Income Protection Insurance',
    'private' => 'Private Medical Insurance',
    'mortgage' => 'Mortgage Protection Insurance',
    'health' => 'Health Insurance',
);

?>

// loop it, in iteration, if the selected value from the first page matches,
// then add the attribute SELECTED
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type">
    <?php foreach($select_values as $value => $name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php echo ($selected == $value) ? 'selected' : '' ; ?> ><?php echo $name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```